# How to convert generic XML to a table row in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql

`PostgresSQL v12.5`

There is a table with single column containing strings formatted as XML.

```
create table XMLDATA (value text);

--------
  text 
--------
<something>  <a>uyt</a>  <b>xyz</b>  </something>
<something>  <a>ryu</a>  <b>sdg</b>  </something>
```

For simplicity let's claim that there are no nesting: all tags inside `<something>` contain primitive values (strings).

Assuming that there are much more elements than `<a>` and `<b>` inside, it would be great to have an option to convert these values into a relational form **without enumerating all of the nested tags manually**.

Was trying to get something in [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-xml.html) related to `XPATH`, `XMLTABLE`, `XPATH_TABLE`, but there are small number of examples that did not help me to reveal the full power of these functions.

What I am looking for is a function `special_function` with results like

```
select * from special_function(XMLDATA);

  a  |  b 
-----------
 uyt | xyz
 ryu | sdg
```

**Could you help me find a functionality of PostgreSQL that automatically recognizes XML tags and convert their content into columns?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *without enumerating all of the nested tags manually.*

That's not possible.

One fundamental restriction of SQL is, that the number, data types and names of all columns need to be known to the database **before** the query starts executing. SQL can't do this "at runtime" and change structure of the query based on data that is retrieved.

---

You can extract the content using `xmltable()` - but as explained, there is no way without specifying each output column.

```
select x.*
from xmldata d
  cross join xmltable('/something' passing d.value
                       columns a  text path 'a', 
                               b  text path 'b') as x
```

This assumes `value` is declared with the data type `xml` (which it should be). If it's not the case, you need to cast it: `passing d.value::xml`

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer.